# Is a very simple theme secure enough?

Tags: themes, security

I am very very new to Wordpress theme development and after creating one, I want to know if any threats will face it. 
There is no way i receive any data from visitors, including no comments received. There are no forms nor any plugins to receive any data.
What I want to know is if the theme I've created is secure enough to be used as a news website or not. 
 Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It’s hard to say without seeing the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the guidelines of the Codex for Themes (start here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development ), and ensure that any user-supplied input (if any) is sanitized, then a theme will be secure.

This also assumes that you have done basic security on your install. For instance:

- strong passwords on all accounts
- create an admin account without the 'admin' name
- take the first user account and demote it to subscriber (not an admin)
- strong passwords for your hosting account
- strong passwords for any FTP users on your hosting account
- keeping all plugins current/updated
- updating WordPress to current levels
- use latest PHP version on your site

Then your site will be less susceptible to attack.  You'll also find lots of security guidelines via the googles. Look at them carefully and apply those that are needed.